# I am scheduling a deletion on my account; will this delete my other Stack Exchange accounts too?

Tags: discussion, accounts, deleted-users

I am deleting my Stack Overflow account, but I am paranoid that it will delete my Arqade account as well. Will it be deleted or will it stay there?

Comment: I would expect it to be per site and [the MSE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account) confirms this, even based on the screenshot of the confirmation page you're shown and had to tick the checkbox on. So if you requested deletion from your user profile on Stack Overflow, only your SO user profile is deleted,  your other accounts are unaffected.

Comment: Also see this Help Center page for basic info about the deletion process: [How do I delete my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the most part, requesting *profile* deletion on one site is completely automated and it's per-site, not network-wide. People use it daily and I've not heard of anything going amiss. Your Arqade profile would not be impacted.

The only exception is if you request *account* data erasure through our legal team—which is generally related to the [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation) "[right to be forgotten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_be_forgotten#General_Data_Protection_Regulation)". This requires a completely separate form and is done manually.